# LWJGL 3 Image Loading?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am using the LWJGL 3 library to build a 2D crafting type game, and I can't get images to load. I have tried using the slick-util library, but that wasn't compatible with LWJGL 3. I have been searching everywhere and everything I have found has been on LWJGL 2, but most of the methods related to images have been changed. Are there any other libraries that work for loading images into textures? Or is there some way to do it with LWJGL 3?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of LWJGL3 has the STB bindings built in, you can use those to load images now. Some details [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-stb-bindings/36153/view.html) on STB.

Comment: Is that the lastest nightly build? I got the latest stable, but I don't see STB anywhere.